# Render components in cell using tanstack tables with Vue3

Tags: vuejs3, tanstack

Using **@tanstack/vue-table**, I am trying to return a component to cell(like react JSX), trying to achieve something like

```
columnHelper.accessor((row) => row.data, {
id: 'Any Id',
cell: (data) => <MyVue3Component/>
})
```

I have tried the `FlexRender(Component, props)` but it doesn't work

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured you can actually achieve this with:

```
 import { h} from 'vue'
    
 columnHelper.accessor((row) => row.data, {
    id: 'Status',
    cell: (data) => h(MyViewComponent)
 })
```

This will render your component in the table cell in vue-3